# TikZ, standalone and bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, bounding-box

I'm aware of tikz' externalize feature, which I don't like because its following 'feature': if I have a picture in the middle of the document, then to externalize it, the inner latex call will process the entire document up to the picture (without output, but it still takes very long time to compile a picture that's far from the beginning of the file). I know that this happens because the entire document may contain code that affects the picture. However, I'd like to tell my system 'look, I don't to such stupid things that have non-local effects'.

So I thought about using standalone. Things like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{pic.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \includestandalone{pic.tex}
\end{document}
```

work nicely; compilation is much faster. However, I also like the `trim left`/`trim right` feature of tikz, or the ability to set a bounding box within the picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[use as bounding box] (0.25,0.25) -- (1.25,1.25);
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a chance to have a similar effect in my tikz-standalone-approach? Basically, I have to somehow get the information what the bounding box is supposed to be from `pic.tex` into the main document.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. If you say `\fbox{\includestandalone{pic.tex}}`, you can see that the bounding box is actually taken into account. What do you expect the output to look like? Do you mean that you keep the bounding box but still show things outside of the box?

Comment: You can use `trim left` and `trim right` together with the `external` library. This would work without `standalone` actually. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15375/47927 .

Comment: @JasperHabicht I explained why I don't want to use `external`: externalizing a single image far from the begin of the document takes too long, because the entire document before it is processed. Today, I externalized all tikz-pictures in a 100p document, and it took > 3 hrs.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, you already wrote that in your question. I just wanted to point to the fact that it would actually work this way. You could probably export a PDF with some information regarding the TrimBox or CropBox, I think, but I am unsure whether it is possible to get this information back from the PDF in order to create a bounding box in the document where you incude this PDF. This would at least be a way that could work, I would imagine.

Comment: Another idea could be to define a custom `\if` and wrap those parts of your code that you don't want to be parsed when doing the first run. Set it to `false` for the first run and this way commenting out what should not be parsed, then set it back to `true` for every following run. This way, you can speed up the run where the externalisation takes place. If your externalised pictures do not depend on the context of the main TeX file, this should work.

Comment: Possible, but would need some implementation effort and TikZ-standalone integration. For now, you can do the task manually by noting that if you pass `trim=<margin amount>` without `clip` flag in `includegraphics`, then you will get the desired behavior, and passing them to `includestandalone` should pass them verbatim to `\includegraphics`. (there's also `adjustbox` package I believe) And also maybe changing the `pagebox` option...?